# DB properties in multiple configuration files

Tags: java, hibernate, quartz-scheduler

In our struts2 webapplication we are using Hibernate ORM for DB communication.  We configured all the connection properties in the default hibernate.cfg.xml file. The connection properties changes from environment to environement i.e., they are different in Local dev system, beta, staging & on live.

Recently i have added quartz.properties files so that the scheduled jobs details are stored in the DB. I am providing the DB properties again in quartz.properties like

```
#quartz table prefixes in the database

org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false



#The details of the datasource specified previously

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/gsraisin

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.user = root

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.password = rootAdmin

org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.maxConnections = 20
```

Is there way that i can use the properties in a single location, i.e, if possible in hibernte.cfg.xml and then use the same details for Quartz app. Please suggest me accordingly.

Comment: Why not add the contents of the quartz.properties in a file having database properties and use them?

Comment: how can i use the hibernate.cfg.xml  file properties in quartz.properties file? Any help would be appreciated.